# JUnit Eclipse can't run unit test

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, jboss-arquillian

i would like to run UNIT test with JUnit in Eclipse, but i got the following error:

```
org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.DeploymentException: Cannot deploy: apm-server-webservices-test.war
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.deployInternal(ArchiveDeployer.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.deployInternal(ArchiveDeployer.java:64)
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.deploy(ArchiveDeployer.java:46)
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.CommonDeployableContainer.deploy(CommonDeployableContainer.java:144)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:161)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:128)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.executeOperation(ContainerDeployController.java:271)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.deploy(ContainerDeployController.java:127)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createDeploymentContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.DeploymentExceptionHandler.verifyExpectedExceptionDuringDeploy(DeploymentExceptionHandler.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$1.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$1.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:80)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:263)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachManagedDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:239)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.deployManaged(ContainerDeployController.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeClass(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:182)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:199)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"apm-server-webservices-test.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"apm-server-webservices-test.war\".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"apm-server-webservices-test.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS018757: Error getting reflective information for class com.sbpsystems.apm.domain.ejb.AdminBean with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.apm-server-webservices-test.war:main\" from Service Module Loader
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp from [Module \"deployment.apm-server-webservices-test.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.getActionResult(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:134)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.getResultFromNode(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:123)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.get(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.get(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:42)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.ServerDeploymentHelper.deploy(ServerDeploymentHelper.java:50)
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.deployInternal(ArchiveDeployer.java:77)
    ... 90 more
```

In com.sbpsystems.apm.domain.ejb pom.xml I have the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.52</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And in my com.sbpsystems.apm.domain.web-services too, where are my unit tests:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.52</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: Can you look into the `jsch` jar (`unzip -l`) and check if the jar contains `ChannelSftp` ? Another idea: you can try to change the scope from `provided` to `test`.

Comment: Yes i saw it, and its there. Yes i tried test scope too. Same problem.
If i i delete the methods and import which use this class then the problem is gone, but this is a working live EJB. Soo the dependency itself is good. Just the unitTest fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** I now got time to build a small sample using arquillian showing the same kinds of exceptions you are facing.

*What does the maven scopes **provided** & **test** do:*

The specified dependency is expected to be provided by the container/runtime running your artifact (scope *provided*) or at the time the test are run (scope *test*).

*What the exception tells us*:

The arquillian container you are using for your micro-deployment is missing the dependencies you have mentioned.

*Solutions:*

One way to solve your problem is to add the missing dependency to your (shrinkwrapped) arquillian-deployment by using *addPackages(true,"com.jcraft.jsch")*.
Unfortunately, this won't mimic your real deployment where com.jcrat.jsch is of scope provided.
(Adding a library to your micro-deployment would resemble scope *complie*).

Another way to solve your problem is to add the library as a module to the jboss your deploying to. 
As com.jcraft.jsch is of scope 'provided' you would need to do this for your real deployment anyway.

Comment: Thanks.

I added the jar to the jboss as a module, then i added this module to the jboss-deployment-structure.xml. 

Now it's working fine.